# Use addcslashes to escape backslash in PHP?

Tags: php, escaping, backslash

I am trying to add another `\` in front of every `\` in a `string` using [addcslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php).

Why doesn't this work?

```
// $string is `\` from user input
$string = addcslashes($string, '\\');
// I apply $string2 = preg_replace('/ /', $string, '/ /');
// $string2 is `\` instead of `\\`
```

This doesn't work either `$string = addcslashes($string, '\\\\')`

**LE:** 
After that I save the string to the file like this:

```
 $pattern = "/db_name = .*;/";
 $newpat = 'db_name = '. export_var($_POST['db_name']) .';';
 $contents = preg_replace($pattern, $newpat, $contents);
```

Comment: What are you adding them for?

Comment: can you please show error message you receiving?

Comment: @clearshot66 Because the user input will be written in a PHP file and if it has unescaped backslashes the next character after backslash will be escaped.

Comment: @ImranQamer No error, just that the backslash is not escaped.

Comment: Working for me http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/705d8f8433858bd5aefaa3affd8c6dfce0fcc193

Comment: @clearshot66 It's `addclsashes` not `addslashes`.

Comment: @apokryfos That seems to be working, let me check why it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: I'd check if either (a) What you're seeing is not an artefact of where you're printing the text or (b) you're not using the result in a way that would evaluate it.

Comment: @apokryfos So, I use the resulted string in a `preg_replace`, something like: `preg_replace($pattern, $string, $file)`. Can the `preg_replace` somehow drop the extra `backslash` ?

Comment: It apparently does: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c65a22e610b7cb1982cb3695a73f68f367695ab2

Answer (score 1):

> the user input will be written in a PHP file

If you want to get a valid literal representation of a value, use [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export), don't try to fiddle with slashes manually:

```
echo '$foo = ', var_export($userInput, true), ';';
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I'm looking for. Is it safe to use without sanitizing the input in any other way? My use case is: user enters string variable value, I set it in code as `$string = var_export($userInput, true);` and save it to a file for later use.

Comment: If you check that the type of the value is a string, and you dump it with `var_export`, and you're not screwing up the syntax where you write it into the file, then it should be good to go.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, if the `$userInput` is a backslash, it's not escaped :(

Comment: I'd generally question the wisdom of generating PHP code though, why not store the input as data?

Comment: So, the users can enter their database connection info. I get the database name from a form and save it in a dbconfig.php file for later use. Any idea of what's the best way to do that? I can't really seem to be able to escape the backslashes...

Comment: Look at the link above; does the same work differently for you, and/or what else do you expect?

Comment: Most likely it's a problem with how I "paste" the value in the file contents, or with `file_put_contents` itself.

Comment: Also, why not save the credentials to a plain text file, or a JSON file or something and read them from there? It doesn't *have* to be hardcoded into PHP.

Comment: Because the dbconfig file is included in every page of my aplication and I think having it hardcoded improves a bit the performance (rather then reading an extra file each time).

Comment: The problem is the `preg_replace` function, when I use `$string` inside it, the backslashes are removed.

Answer (score 0):

this may help you.

```
//$string =  'this is my first slash `\` and this is second `\`';

echo $string = str_replace('`\`','`\\\\`',$string);

//output: this is my first slash `\\` and this is second `\\`
```

It is giving me desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was actually the `preg_replace` call replacing the `\\` with `\`.

To fix this issue this is how I escape my string before it can be used in `preg_replace`.

```
function sanitizeStr($string) {
    // We have to double each backslash as preg_replace de-doubles it.
    $string = str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $string);
    return var_export($string, true);
}
$string = sanitizeStr($string);
$contents = preg_replace($pattern, $string, $contents);
```

How, after the replace, `$contents` will contain the `$string` exactly as the user inputted it, but safe to use output it in a PHP file.

Thanks to @deceze for mentioning `var_export`.